# Getting physical memory information in Android?

Tags: android, memory-management

I'm trying to get info about the physical memory such as total memory, used memory and free memory and not just about the heap.

I've searched for such questions here but didn't find a correct answer.

I've tried this way:

```
long freeSize = 0L;
    long totalSize = 0L;
    long usedSize = 0L;


    try {
        Runtime info = Runtime.getRuntime();
        freeSize = info.freeMemory();
        totalSize = info.totalMemory();
        usedSize = totalSize - freeSize;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But don't obtain correct information.

Also I tried with MemoryInfo class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**GET current RAM :**

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
```

Comment: Yes, I used this way as well but it gives me only the available memory. I want to find out the total memory as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way to calculate memory usage of currently running application.**

```
public static long getUsedMemorySize() {

    long freeSize = 0L;
    long totalSize = 0L;
    long usedSize = -1L;
    try {
        Runtime info = Runtime.getRuntime();
        freeSize = info.freeMemory();
        totalSize = info.totalMemory();
        usedSize = totalSize - freeSize;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return usedSize;

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's almost the same as the sample I provided above. But the problem is not the usage of the currently running application. I want to know what is the total size of the phone's RAM and also the currently used and available ones. 
Thanks for the sample thou! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
            activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

            String TAG = "a";
            Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.availMem " + memoryInfo.availMem + "\n" );
            Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.lowMemory " + memoryInfo.lowMemory + "\n" );
            Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.threshold " + memoryInfo.threshold + "\n" );

            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

            Map<Integer, String> pidMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
            for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : runningAppProcesses)
            {
                pidMap.put(runningAppProcessInfo.pid, runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
            }

            Collection<Integer> keys = pidMap.keySet();

            for(int key : keys)
            {
                int pids[] = new int[1];
                pids[0] = key;
                android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo[] memoryInfoArray = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids);
                for(android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo pidMemoryInfo: memoryInfoArray)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("** MEMINFO in pid %d [%s] **\n",pids[0],pidMap.get(pids[0])));
                    Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty() + "\n");
                    Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss() + "\n");
                    Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty() + "\n");
                }
            }
```